# global sql table or folder that reachable from all application

Tags: android, file, sqlite

Is there any sql table or folder that reachable from all application in android.

I can create it in sdcard but, some devices have not sdcard. so it should be in device memory. is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to write Content providers it mays you it will give ur database access to all applications in the device.

have a look into this tutorial how to create a content provider and etc.. stuff

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use content provider, it stores and retrive data and make it available for all applications http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html